# armeabi-v7a executable compiles but .so doesn't?

Tags: android, c++, makefile, build, compilation

I can successfully compile an executable with the following flags:

```
CXX_FLAGS = -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes \
                   -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -fexceptions -frtti  -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIE
CXXFLAGS_LINK = $(CXX_FLAGS) -pie -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc
```

But I want to have a .so file so I changed the flags to:

```
CXX_FLAGS = -march=armv7-a -mthumb -mfpu=neon -mfloat-abi=softfp -funwind-tables -no-canonical-prefixes \
        -D__ANDROID_API__=16 -fexceptions -frtti  -std=c++11 -O3 -DNDEBUG -fPIC
CXXFLAGS_LINK = $(CXX_FLAGS) -fPIC -g  -shared -Wl,-export-dynamic -Wl,--fix-cortex-a8 -Wl,--gc-sections -Wl,-z,nocopyreloc
```

Unfortunately this leads to the following error (which is printed 26 times in a row whyever?):

```
/opt/android-ndk-r17c/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.9/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/bin/../lib/gcc/arm-linux-androideabi/4.9.x/../../../../arm-linux-androideabi/bin/ld: error: ocr_db_crnn.o: requires unsupported dynamic reloc R_ARM_REL32; recompile with -fPIC
```

and finally:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Strangely I have zero problems compiling with the exact same Makefile for arm64-v8a both shared and executable, they work. The only difference is the toolchain of the same NDK.

I am not experienced in cxx building so I hope that I did an obvious/stupid mistake somewhere? Thanks in advance for any kind of help

Comment: Is there a reason you are using an ancient version of the android NDK? 17c was released five years ago. And Android API 16 is likewise ancient (we are up to 33 by now)

Comment: I don't know what your intention is but to build a native shared library you can simply use Android Studio. It does everything for you. You don't have to worry about any compiler flags.

Comment: I will definitely try that, but it will forever bug me if I won't find out what the problem is. Especially since it builds for arm64 without any problems.

Comment: @Botje I just started my experiments, does it have no drawbacks if I use the newest ndk? I also tried with r20b which didn't change the error so does it really matter? And 16 is just the minapi. If I set it to 21 the error is the same. I'm basically following more or less a tutorial that showed how to compile for arm64, now I'm trying to do 32 bit.

Comment: In the contrary: newer NDKs will get you newer compilers (fewer bugs ,better diagnostics) and newer target SDKs will give you a larger portion of the C standard library.

Comment: @Botje I tried with r24 and the first I get is a totally new error at the very beginning, <<<</opt/android-ndk-r24/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/include/__config:218:12: fatal error: 'features.h' file not found
#  include <features.h>
>>>> The older NDK didn't seem to have any problems with that, why?

Comment: features.h is inside the sysroot provided as part of the NDK. Are you not referencing that in your build?

Comment: @Botje     INCLUDES = $(SYSTEM_INCLUDES) -I$(NDK_ROOT)/sysroot/usr/include/arm-linux-androideabi     Well if I change it back to r17c, it finds the .h. But I just noticed that r24 doesn't even have a sysroot? Why is that

Comment: That's now how you include a sysroot... Should be something like `--sysroot $(NDK_ROOT)/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot`. Change the `darwin-x86_64` bit as needed. Consult the [cross-compiling documentation](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/other_build_systems#non-autoconf_make_projects) and-or edit your question with an actual [mre]

Comment: @Botje Alright I got it working, now it crashed at the same point as with the older NDK but with a more detailed error message, I uploaded it on pastebin: https://pastebin.com/citUMEdd

Comment: Very stupid question, but .. did you remove your .o files inbetween changing the makefile?

Comment: @Botje No and they are still there :  https://gyazo.com/06b1d8853beb157306377bea9a1993d6

Comment: Unless the Makefile has special accommodations for this, you should probably run `make clean` after you fiddle with `CXX_FLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS_LINK`.

Comment: @Botje Oh damn... that seems to be the problem solver. So when switching build targets architectures always run make clean. Noted :D Thank you very much. I'll test the result .so in my app.

Comment: You never showed your build system, but many build systems support "out of tree" builds, such that you can have several in parallel for different configurations (debug vs release, arm vs intel)

Comment: @Botje I just downloaded a preconfigured docker image, not even sure what exactly it is, and built from there. Just making some experiments. By the way the .so works perfectly in the app. Thank you a lot because I literally spent the last 8 hours trying to find out what this strange error is about and I had absolutely no perspective in solving it alone